# Empty readonly Action delegate

Tags: c#, .net

There are a number of places in our code where `() => {}` is used (required `Action` parameter in methods of third-party library).
To make code cleaner I created the following class:

```
public static class Empty
{
    public static readonly Action Action = () => {};
}
```

Now it is much nicer:

```
Alert.Show(title, message, Empty.Action);
```

The question is may this refactoring cause any problems? I'm sure no but you may know possible side cases. Or may be you know better code improvement here?

Comment: I may be weird, but I find `()=>{}` quite readable, and it definitely says "do nothing" (to me at least)...

Comment: So I'm not crazy. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This change is technically observable: there is always the possibility that some code indirectly compares two `new Action(() => {})` instances for equality, and where they would previously not compare equal, they do now.

For an example, if you expose an `public event Action X;`, you might make sure to initialise it to `() => {}` to make sure it's never `null`, and remove any `null` checks from your code. If you change this to `Empty.Action`, then malicious code could write `X -= Empty.Action;`, causing a `NullReferenceException` in your own code where the event gets invoked.

But in well-written code, the refactoring should not make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

This will not cause any problems, as it is equivalent to defining a static method and referencing it multiple times in your assembly